# Running PowerShell Script Hidden in the Background and on Startup

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm working on an **educational** project where I've created a PowerShell script and saved it in a .ps1 file. The script performs some tasks, and I want it to run without showing the PowerShell window to the user. Additionally, I'd like the script to run in the background and automatically start every time the user restarts their computer. **Please note that this is solely for educational purposes.**

I've tried a few things, like using the -WindowStyle Hidden argument with powershell.exe to hide the window, but it's not running in the background as I intended. Is there a way I can achieve both running the script hidden and ensuring it runs on startup? Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

And I'm telling again: **THIS IS ONLY FOR EDUCATIONAL AND ETHICAL PURPOSES**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe a scheduled task would do better. And why tag Linux, Windows and two specific Powershell versions? You really need 2.0 support?

Comment: When you say you tried "using the -WindowStyle Hidden argument", is that on Windows 11, as that feature is currently bugged if you have Windows Terminal enabled (which comes enabled in Win11), you can revert it back to Windows Host Console instead of terminal though. Either that or just run your script as System via a task, then it will be hidden.

Comment: @KG-DROID Thank you for your response, but unfortunately, the suggestions you mentioned regarding the `-WindowStyle Hidden` argument and running the script as System via a task didn't produce the desired outcome in my Windows 10 environment. The script still doesn't run in the background as intended, and it doesn't automatically start on system restart. Since this is for educational purposes, I'm hoping to find a solution that fulfills these requirements. If you or anyone else has further insights or alternative approaches, I would be grateful for your assistance. Thank you.

Comment: @vonPryz I appreciate your engagement and your suggestion regarding a scheduled task. I'll certainly look into that option as an alternative approach.

To clarify, my goal is to create a PowerShell script that runs silently in the background without displaying a window to the user. Additionally, I want the script to initiate automatically every time the user's computer restarts.

I understand your point about the tags and fixed those tags.Your attention to detail is appreciated. If you have any more insights to share, I'm all ears. Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide more details about what didnt work with the windowstyle hidden, by didnt work do you mean it flashes the window up quickly when it starts? Also have you tried converting the script for PS2EXE: https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE ?

Comment: @KG-DROID Thank you for your continued assistance, KG-DROID. When I tried using -WindowStyle Hidden, the issue was that the PowerShell window still briefly flashed on the screen when the script started, which isn't ideal for my purposes.

Thanks for suggesting PS2EXE. However, it appears to be Windows-specific, and I'm working with Kali Linux. I need a solution compatible with Linux. Any Linux-based recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: ah ok, I don't really know anything Linux to be honest unfortunately